# Magento 2 Fatal Error on Setup page

Tags: magento2

When I try to access localhost/magento/setup this window is shown

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: The each()
>   function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further
>   calls in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php
>   on line 81 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'The each()
>   func...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 81, Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php(81):
>   each(Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache.php(153):
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Cache.php(94):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory.php(156):
>   Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...',
>   Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magent in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php
>   on line 61

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that's because you're on PHP 7.2 that is not currently supported by Magento2